How to mix polymorphism and templates
I have a base class, let's call it Node for the sake of argument, that will have an arbitrary number of leaf implementations. Let's just restrict it to two for now: NodeA and NodeB. They require different arguments to construct.
I want to create a node, and I have a factory class for this purpose. The factory has a template function
template<typename NodeType, typename...Args>
Node * createNode(Args&&... args) 
{
    auto const node = new NodeType(std::forward(args)...);
    /* other stuff*/
    return node;
}

This allows me to create new node types without having to worry about adding extra create functions to the factory
auto const nodeA = factory->createNode<NodeA>("foo", 10);
auto const nodeB = factory->createNode<NodeB>("bar", "wibble", 100.0f);

But here's the twist: the actual type returned will not just depend on the NodeType parameter, but also the factory type.
class NodeA1 : public NodeA {/*stuff*/};

class Factory1 : public Factory
{
    /* C++ won't allow me to virtualise (or overload?) createNode*/
    template<typename NodeType, typename...Args>
    Node * createNode(Args&&...args)
    {
        /* If NodeType is A, I want to return new NodeA1() */
        ???
    }
};

I don't want to have an interface like
class Factory
{
    virtual Node * createNodeA(/*A args*/) = 0;
    virtual Node * createNodeB(/*B args*/) = 0;
};

because that scales badly (every factory type is affected by argument changes and has to be extended to create new types). I fear I may inevitably have to do this, but wondered if there was a cleaner way of implementing this design? Or indeed a better design!

sounds like the abstract factory design pattern. (not to be confused with factory pattern, where you have one factory creating N types, in the abstract factory pattern you have M factories creating N different types of objects)

Yoi also need type-erasure which joins the gap between polymorphism and generics,  for example instead of Args it will take NodeA_Construction_Args struct through an std::any and use it to construct NodeA

@463035818_is_not_an_ai It is kind of that, but the abstract factory is based on a common interface - ie being able to make the creation functions virtual. Here, because C++ won't let me virtualise a templated method, I can't really do that. And would need to resort to the brute-force "createNodeA, createNodeB" approach.

First of all, NodeType needs to be NodeA1, not NodeA. Then, you can require (and enforce this through C++23 requires) that each NodeType defines type Base. Then, your factory can create NodeType and return NodeType::Base*. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

This video is exactly about your problem CppCon 2014: Cheinan Marks "Practical Type Erasure" of using type-erasure to join polymorphism and generics, note that you can just store pointers to stack objects inside std::any so no heap allocation is required

@lobelk since the factory interface is abstract, I don't (and shouldn't) know about the existence of NodeA1 so it can't be a template argument in client code.

The problem with this question is that there is no details about requirements of Node and relation of this requirements to NodeA NodeB. Depending on this information simple polymorphism can be a solution, but it may turn out more complex type erasure should be implemented or completely different solution.

So what the client does know? It looks like it knows all of NodeA, NodeB etc.

How do your factories actually need to differ? Do they alter the returned object in predictable ways, or allocate it in different free stores, or something else?

@Useless so the factories will return different class types. They don't modify anything as such. But Factory1 will return a NodeA1 and NodeB1 which will implement virtual functions potentially radically different from NodeA2 and NodeB2 from Factory2.

Ok, so the NodeType template parameter is a tag or something, and not actually the Node subclass you want to construct?

@Useless it does refer to a base class that has fields and methods. But the subclasses of NodeA etc will implement "payload" members that behave (potentially very) differently.

The typical approach is using type-erasure, the amount of type-erasure that you use depends on what needs to be extensible and what is concrete.
since createNode is templated, it cannot be virtual, the best it can do is to convert its arguments into a type-erased object that is later passed into a virtual function, let's call that createNode_impl.
Each factory will use this type-erased object to resolve the type needed (NodeA, NodeB, etc..) then construct its own version of it (NodeA1, etc..)
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <memory>

struct Node {
    Node() = default;
    Node(Node&&) = default;
    Node(const Node&) = default;
    Node& operator=(Node&&) = default;
    Node& operator=(const Node&) = default;
    virtual ~Node() = default;

    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct ConstructionArgs
{
    // you need a vtable to dynamic_cast
    virtual std::string_view name() = 0;
};


struct NodeA : public Node
{
    NodeA(std::string s) : data{ std::move(s) } {}
    std::string data;
};

template <typename T>
struct SpecificConstructionArgs;

template <>
struct SpecificConstructionArgs<NodeA>: public ConstructionArgs
{
    std::string_view name() override
    {
        return "NodeA";
    }
    std::string data = "some_data";
};

struct AbstractFactory
{
    template <typename T, typename...Args>
    std::unique_ptr<Node> createNode(Args&&...args)
    {
        auto arg = SpecificConstructionArgs<T>{ std::forward<Args>(args)... };
        return createNode_impl(arg);
    }
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Node> createNode_impl(ConstructionArgs& args) = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractFactory() = default;
};

struct NodeA1 : public NodeA
{
    using NodeA::NodeA;
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A1"; }
};

struct Factory1 : public AbstractFactory
{
    std::unique_ptr<Node> createNode_impl(ConstructionArgs& args) override
    {
        if (auto* obj = dynamic_cast<SpecificConstructionArgs<NodeA>*>(&args))
        {
            return std::make_unique<NodeA1>( std::move(obj->data) );
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Factory1 f;
    auto obj = f.createNode<NodeA>();
    obj->foo();
}

goldbolt Demo
An alternative to dynamic_cast that doesn't use RTTI is to use std::any with a pointer (but also doesn't work across dll boundaries) or std::variant of all the argument types (will work across dll boundaries but beware of ABI compatibility) or add an enum to the ConstructArgs object.

I like this, and have learnt a lot from it. It suffers from one issue that I would be keen to avoid. The leaf factory classes need to know about every type of node so it can dynamic_cast. This makes it a compilation bottleneck and adding new node subclasses becomes error-prone. I like the general framework though, so will spend some time figuring out how to further abstract so I can add new node types without having to edit lots of code.

@jg_at_pharos you can use the composite pattern for that where each factory only knows about 1 type and you can have factories made up of many factories that it loops over, if any of child factories handles it then you return.
